# Access denied with MySQL root password

Tags: server, mysql

I installed MySQL on Ubuntu 22.04 and made a mistake.

When I do `su - mysql -u root` or `su - mysql -u root` I get `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` How can I get this to work again?

```
[1]+  Stopped                 mysql
root@ubuntu-instance1:~# sudo mysql -u root

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g. Your MySQL connection id is 16 Server version: 8.0.31-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 (Ubuntu)

mysql>
update user set plugin='' where User='root';
flush privileges;

Database changed
mysql> 
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0**
```

Comment: Apologies, I don't understand what the pasted output has to do with the question. Have you broken your `root` MySQL account? If so, you will need to use the administration account that should have been created after installing MySQL. If you did not create an admin account and only used `root`, then you may have hosed that account, meaning only a re-installation of MySQL will resolve the issue 

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1709138/13305177 (safe mode and skip-grant-tables), but if you don't have any data, just deleting everything and installing again will be easier